# Datatable header and body getting misaligned

Tags: angular, datatables

I have created a datatable using jquery datatable in Angular 6 project. In my case the columns can be toggled by the user using a form in a popup.

Below is the popup:

[image]

When the user selects/deselects the respective column headers and saves, I do the following steps;

1. Filter the array to get only headers that need to be shown
2. Destroy the datatable using

```js
$(".data-table").DataTable().destroy();
```

3. Reinitialize the datatable using:

```js
var table = $(".data-table").DataTable({
    dom:
      "<'row'<'#tblnoitfy'>><'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-8'p>>" +
      "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>",
    fixedHeader: {
      header: true,
      footer: true
    },
    scrollY: "calc(100vh - 154px)",
    paging: false,
    scrollX: true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    searching: false,
    bDestroy: true,
    bAutoWidth: true,
    bDeferRender: true,
    info: false,
    aaSorting: [],
    language: {
      emptyTable: " "
    }
  });

  $(".dataTables_empty").append(this.noDataHtml());
});
```

Once I do this, all my headers and its data gets misaligned. The effect is visible when we horizontally scroll the datatable .

How can i resolve this issue.!

Comment: What does `$(".dataTables_empty").append(this.noDataHtml())` do? I had the inpression that you were rendering the table using Angular?

Comment: @davidkonard yes I'm using it in the Angular app.